# OpenCL: Page flipping / ping-pong buffer with image3D?

Tags: opencl

I want to implement an algorithm in openCL which needs to apply a certain transformation on a **3D** grayscale image several times. I have an input and an output image for my kernel. Now I would like to simply swap the input and output image and apply the kernel again. However, one image was created with read_only and the other one with write_only. Does this mean I have to use conventional buffers, or is there some trick, how to flip the two images, without first copying them from the device back to the host and back to the device again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: *"However, one image was created with read_only and the other one with write_only"*. The obvious answer is: **don't do that, and you'll be fine**.

The less obvious subtext is: There's a difference between *creating an image with writeonly/readonly flags* (which is done on the host-side via `clCreateImage(...,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY/CL_MEM_READ_ONLY)`) and the access-type inside a particular kernel (which is specified with the `__read_only`/`__write_only` qualifiers in the kernel's arguments definition).

Unless I'm totally mistaken, you can safely create your image with no restrictions (i.e. `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`), then use it as a kernel's input parameter, and for the next kernel run, use it as the output parameter. You just can't mix read/write accesses *during a single kernel run*.

Comment: Addon: Host side flags are used for schedules. If you have 2 GPUs running 2 kernels that use the same parameter, it will not block one of the kernels, since the images are read_only (therefore safe to parallelize). For the kernel side, it is just similar to a "const" to ensure user does not write to them accidentally. The easier solution here is as you said do not enforce any Host side flags, and you are done.